# Error in building and running Elasticsearch Source Code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to import and run Elasticsearch source code into an IntelliJ IDEA project, for that :

1. I have cloned the latest Elasticsearch Source Code from the official Github repository https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch.

`JAVA_HOME` is set to `/home/bhavya/.jenv/versions/11`

2. Then I imported the project into IntelliJ IDEA
3. Now when I run the elastic search from IntelliJ IDEA, using `build.gradle`, following response is generated

   ```
    4:41:23 PM: Executing task...

    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:compileJava
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:processResources NO-SOURCE
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:classes
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:jar
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:assemble
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:test NO-SOURCE
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:check UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :buildSrc:reaper:build

    > Task :buildSrc:compileJava
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

    > Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy
    Note: /home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/elasticsearch/gradle/test/TestWithSslPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/home/bhavya/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-all/2oz4ud9k3tuxjg84bbf55q0tn/gradle-6.5/lib/groovy-all-1.3-2.5.11.jar) to method java.util.AbstractCollection.finishToArray(java.lang.Object[],java.util.Iterator)
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

    > Task :buildSrc:generateVersionProperties UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :buildSrc:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :buildSrc:classes
    > Task :buildSrc:jar
    > Task :buildSrc:assemble
    > Task :buildSrc:pluginUnderTestMetadata
    > Task :buildSrc:compileTestFixturesJava
    > Task :buildSrc:compileTestFixturesGroovy NO-SOURCE
    > Task :buildSrc:processTestFixturesResources NO-SOURCE
    > Task :buildSrc:testFixturesClasses
    > Task :buildSrc:testFixturesJar
    > Task :buildSrc:compileTestJava
    > Task :buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
    > Task :buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :buildSrc:testClasses
    > Task :buildSrc:test SKIPPED
    > Task :buildSrc:validatePlugins
    > Task :buildSrc:check
    > Task :buildSrc:build
    =======================================
    Elasticsearch Build Hamster says Hello!
      Gradle Version        : 6.5
      OS Info               : Linux 5.3.0-62-generic (amd64)
      JDK Version           : 14 (OpenJDK)
      JAVA_HOME             : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1
      Random Testing Seed   : FABD41EAA6CF4507
      In FIPS 140 mode      : false
    =======================================

    > Task :help

    Welcome to Gradle 6.5.

    To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

    To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

    To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

    To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

    For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 19s
    1 actionable task: 1 executed
    4:41:42 PM: Task execution finished.
   ```
4. Now according to [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-to-the-elasticsearch-codebase), when I run Elasticsearch using command `./gradlew :run` from the terminal, I get the following errors :

**Error**

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option AggressiveOpts was deprecated in version 11.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
=======================================
Elasticsearch Build Hamster says Hello!
  Gradle Version        : 6.5
  OS Info               : Linux 5.3.0-62-generic (amd64)
  JDK Version           : 11 (JDK)
  JAVA_HOME             : /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
  Random Testing Seed   : 2091C4A33F3190DA
  In FIPS 140 mode      : false
=======================================

> Task :x-pack:plugin:monitoring:compileJava FAILED
/home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/x-pack/plugin/monitoring/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/monitoring/exporter/http/HttpExporter.java:114: error: unexpected type
                        public void validate(final List<String> value) {
                                                   ^
  required: class
  found:    <any?>
/home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/x-pack/plugin/monitoring/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/monitoring/exporter/http/HttpExporter.java:114: error: unexpected type
                        public void validate(final List<String> value) {
                                                        ^
  required: reference
  found:    <any?>
/home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/x-pack/plugin/monitoring/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/monitoring/exporter/http/HttpExporter.java:119: error: unexpected type
                        public void validate(final List<String> hosts, final Map<Setting<?>, Object> settings) {
                                                   ^
  required: class
  found:    <any?>
/home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/x-pack/plugin/monitoring/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/monitoring/exporter/http/HttpExporter.java:119: error: unexpected type
                        public void validate(final List<String> hosts, final Map<Setting<?>, Object> settings) {
                                                        ^
  required: reference
  found:    <any?>
/home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/x-pack/plugin/monitoring/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/monitoring/exporter/http/HttpExporter.java:119: error: unexpected type
                        public void validate(final List<String> hosts, final Map<Setting<?>, Object> settings) {
                                                                             ^
  required: class
  found:    <any?>
/home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/x-pack/plugin/monitoring/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/monitoring/exporter/http/HttpExporter.java:119: error: unexpected type
                        public void validate(final List<String> hosts, final Map<Setting<?>, Object> settings) {
                                                                                 ^
  required: class
  found:    <any?>
/home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/x-pack/plugin/monitoring/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/monitoring/exporter/http/HttpExporter.java:119: error: unexpected type
                        public void validate(final List<String> hosts, final Map<Setting<?>, Object> settings) {
                                                                                             ^
  required: reference
  found:    <any?>
/home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/x-pack/plugin/monitoring/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/monitoring/exporter/http/HttpExporter.java:162: error: unexpected type
                        public Iterator<Setting<?>> settings() {
                               ^
  required: class
  found:    <any?>
/home/bhavya/Code/elasticsearch/x-pack/plugin/monitoring/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/monitoring/exporter/http/HttpExporter.java:162: error: unexpected type
                        public Iterator<Setting<?>> settings() {
                                        ^
  required: class
  found:    <any?>
9 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':x-pack:plugin:monitoring:compileJava'.
> java.lang.AssertionError: isSubtype UNKNOWN

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
353 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 349 up-to-date
```

**Note:** When `JAVA_HOME` is set to `/home/bhavya/.jenv/versions/14`, I get the following errors when trying to run Elasticsearch using `./gradlew :run`

```
    Unrecognized VM option 'AggressiveOpts'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Did you follow [these steps](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#importing-the-project-into-intellij-idea)?

Comment: Yes @Val I followed the same steps, as mentioned in `CONTRIBUTING.md` in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: In step 3, we can see that `JDK Version` is not the one you set in step 1, so something must be off. Two different JDKs are used depending on how you build (i.e. through IntelliJ or directly with gradle on the command line)

Comment: @Val Oh ok, maybe that is causing the issue. But when I set `jenv` version to 14, then also I am getting this error `Unrecognized VM option 'AggressiveOpts'`

Comment: `AggressiveOpts` [was deprecated in JDK 11](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-13-what-is-aggressiveopts) so that's maybe the reason

Comment: What do you get when running `gradle -v`? and what do you have as value for `org.gradle.java.home` in `$HOME_DIRECTORY/.gradle/gradle.properties`?

Comment: @Val I am getting the same error when running `gradle -v`, as that mentioned in NOTE section `Unrecognized VM option 'AggressiveOpts'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
`

Comment: Yes, because gradle cannot start at all. See my second question

Comment: @Val I can't find `.gradle` in the home directory. Is it because I have not installed gradle ?

Comment: Actually, since you're using the gradle wrapper provided by elasticsearch, you can check the gradle.properties file at the root of the repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225669/discussion-between-escoder-and-val).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the elasticsearch.
The solution is to upgrade your Java to either openjdk-14-jdk or java-15-oracle.

Both did the job for me

Comment: thanks for your answer. But as you can see in the NOTE section, I have tried running the source code with java version 14 also, but I again got some errors.